# How to make my code simplier and cleaner? (Vendor machine with categories and products from categories)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

How to make my code simplier and cleaner? I know there's a way but I'm a very begginer in a world of development. I think it's not good to write all the way: "if something == "1" then do that and that and all those product in all those categories.... Thank You!

```py
snacks = [
    {"name" : "baton", "price" : 4},
    {"name" : "wafelek", "price" : 6.50},
    {"name" : "orzeszki", "price" : 9.29}
]

drinks = [
    {"name" : "woda", "price" : 2},
    {"name" : "sok", "price" : 3.40},
    {"name" : "cola", "price" : 6.90}
]


bread = [
    {"name" : "bulka", "price" : 1.30},
    {"name" : "paczek", "price" : 2.30},
    {"name" : "zajechleb2000", "price" : 666.66}
]

def choice():
    category_choice = input("Choose your category: ")
    if category_choice == "1":
        choose = input("Choose product: ")
        if choose == "1":
            return snacks[0]

        if choose == "2":
            return snacks[1]

        if choose == "3":
            return snacks[2]

    if category_choice == "2":
        choose = input("Choose product: ")
        if choose == "1":
            return drinks[0]

        if choose == "2":
            return drinks[1]

        if choose == "3":
            return drinks[2]
    
    if category_choice == "3":
        choose = input("Choose product: ")
        if choose == "1":
            return bread[0]

        if choose == "2":
            return bread[1]

        if choose == "3":
            return bread[2]


def buy():
    choose = choice()
    return choose
    

print(buy())
```

Comment: If this is working code, then you should ask this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Ok, i will remember your advice

Answer (score 1):

You can organize all products in a dictionary to easily get their values:

```
products = {
    "snacks": [
    {"name" : "baton", "price" : 4},
    {"name" : "wafelek", "price" : 6.50},
    {"name" : "orzeszki", "price" : 9.29}],

    "drinks": [
    {"name" : "woda", "price" : 2},
    {"name" : "sok", "price" : 3.40},
    {"name" : "cola", "price" : 6.90}],

    "bread": [
    {"name" : "bulka", "price" : 1.30},
    {"name" : "paczek", "price" : 2.30},
    {"name" : "zajechleb2000", "price" : 666.66}]}


def choose():
    product = input("What type of product do you want to choose: ")
    specific = int(input("Choose product: "))

    return products[product][specific]


print(choose())
```

You could tell customer which products are available with:

```
def choose():
    print(list(products.keys()))
    product = input("What type of product do you want to choose: ")
    print(products[product])
    specific = int(input("Choose product: "))

    return products[product][specific]
```

Obviously you could format this better, since this is just a rough example. This prints:

```
['snacks', 'drinks', 'bread']
What type of product do you want to choose: snacks
[{'name': 'baton', 'price': 4}, {'name': 'wafelek', 'price': 6.5}, {'name': 'orzeszki', 'price': 9.29}]
Choose product: 2
{'name': 'orzeszki', 'price': 9.29}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I will study your example in a best way to learn it. :)